# How to understand the claim that ''positions'' of entangled particles are correlated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, epr-experiment

Are both particles detected in the exact same spot of the detector? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we know the total momentum of the entangled pair. For example they might have been created by the decay of a stationary particle in which case the total momentum is zero. That means the momenta of the two particles must be equal and opposite, which means (assuming equal masses) the velocities must be equal and opposite. The positions are just the integrals of the velocities, so the positions must be correlated i.e. if we measure the position of one of the particles we know where the other must be.